# Why is reject not rejecting?

Tags: ruby, dictionary

This code is [my initial stab](http://exercism.io/submissions/90f128ee2e9541f0b62491e05ca8add0) at the Hamming Distance problem on Exercism.io, but it fails the case when string `a` is longer than string `b`, and I'm trying to understand why.

```
def self.compute(a, b)
  a.split('').reject.with_index { |c, i| c == b[i] }.size
end
```

I got around the problem by trimming the first string...

```
def self.compute(a, b)
  a[0...b.size].split('').reject.with_index { |c, i| c == b[i] }.size
end
```

...but I don't understand why `reject` is including the extra characters.  When I check the comparisons, they seem to be coming up false, as I would expect, yet are still included in the result.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: It's because when you're rejecting, `false` _means_ include.

Comment: `split('')` is the same as `split`. Make your life easier and save the four characters.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, @the Tin Man, but it doesn't seem to be the case. `split` with no arguments seems to default to splitting on whitespace.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split

Comment: You're right. I was thinking you wanted to split on words/whitespace. `split('')` splits on characters, which is the same as using `chars`. Which also saves four characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why reject is including the extra characters. When I check the comparisons, they seem to be coming up false

Correct. And when you're rejecting, `false` means "accept" - the opposite of reject.

The problem is merely that you're not grasping what "reject" means. When you're up against a question like this, *debug*. In this case, the way to do that is to eliminate the superfluous material and focus on the thing that's confusing you. Remove the `size` call and just look at the results of the `reject` call:

```
def compute(a, b)
  a.split('').reject.with_index { |c, i| c == b[i] }
end
result = compute("hey", "ha")
puts result
```

The output is `"e"` and `"y"`. And this makes sense:

- On the first pass, `"h"` == `"h"` and is rejected.
- On the second pass, `"e"` != `"a"` and is accepted.
- On the third pass, `"y"` has nothing to compare it with, so it cannot succeed; thus we fail *to reject* — and so the `"y"` is accepted. That's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that involves a lot of sorting and is probably sub-optimal, but might serve as the basis for a more efficient solution:

```
def ham(a,b)
  [ a.length, b.length ].sort[1].times.reject do |i|
    a[i] != b[i]
  end.sort[-1]
end

pairs = [
  ['A', 'A'],
  ['A','G'],
  ['AG','CT'],
  ['AT','CT'],
  ['GGACG', 'GGTCG'],
  ['AGAGACTTA', 'AAA'],
  ['AGG', 'AAAACTGACCCACCCCAGG'],
  ['GATACA', 'GCATAA'],
  ['GGACGGATTCTG', 'AGGACGGATTCT']
]

pairs.each do |pair|
  puts '%s -> %s' % [ pair.inspect, ham(*pair).inspect ]
end

# ["A", "A"] -> 0
# ["A", "G"] -> nil
# ["AG", "CT"] -> nil
# ["AT", "CT"] -> 1
# ["GGACG", "GGTCG"] -> 4
# ["AGAGACTTA", "AAA"] -> 2
# ["AGG", "AAAACTGACCCACCCCAGG"] -> 0
# ["GATACA", "GCATAA"] -> 5
# ["GGACGGATTCTG", "AGGACGGATTCT"] -> 8
```

It looks like in your version you're not comparing the longest string to the shortest one if there's a difference in length. Sorting them by length fixes this problem.